# How to host my own website with my own html documents

Tags: html, web, dns, hosting

I know this is the most basic of questions. I made my own website in HTML documents. I bought a domain name from google. How can I publish this, how can I host it? I don't want to use any website creator, I want to publish my own files that I worked on.

Comment: There are a lot of different hosts. The easiest two I like to use are Netlify and Github Pages. Both support custom domains without additional costs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I would like to use my own .com domain, but I am having trouble using any hosting service, namely ghost. I am looking for resources to learn but every service wants me to either use their website builder or expects me to know everything at an expert level.

Comment: you can use netlify, it allows you to upload your own html file and use your own domain, dev ed channel has a guide for this

Comment: i hope this can help you https://youtu.be/tTKnuVx5qWA

Comment: I can only agree, Netlify has been the best solution for me personally. If you don't know how to set it up, here's [an article about it](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/29/a-step-by-step-guide-deploying-on-netlify/). You also have the option to set your [custom domain](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/) (i.e. example.com) via the DNS records .

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Github** to host your website on your own domain.
You have to add the whole files needed for the website. Then in the settings of your repo use the Github pages feature and enable it. Change the source of Github pages to host in your own domain. Then you have to add some **A** and **CNAME** records of your domain to point to github servers.

Here are the full steps for the process - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/publish-websites-on-github-pages-with-a-custom-domain/

Comment: Additionally, you can connect your GitHub site to Netlify for even more features. Just check out this article ( https://www.netlify.com/github-pages-vs-netlify/ ) to find out more about the differences.